# Server Push requests are not supported by the AJP Protocol

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, push-notification, http2

I am implementing **HTTP/2 Server Push features on a Website deployed in Apache Tomcat 9.0.0.** The Push features work fine when I access the website directly through Tomcat.
However, the problem arises when I try to access the website through a proxy server. I have configured Apache HTTP 2.4.18 Server to redirect the requests to Tomcat Server using the mod_jk connector. This redirection successfully returns responses other features of the Website but does not return the Push Requests.

Following is the **error** message which I get when I access the website from Apache HTTP Server.

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Server push requests are not supported by the AJP protocol
org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.action(AjpProcessor.java:612)
org.apache.coyote.Request.action(Request.java:392)
http2.SimpleImagePush.doGet(SimpleImagePush.java:73)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
```

**Kindly help me to fix the above errors.**

Is this problem related to enabling the **Nio Protocol Connector?**

Is there a specific configuration to add to **server.xml** file in Tomcat to support the server push requests?

Do I need to upgrade the **AJP Version?**